# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while inserting datetime SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I inserted some columns from an excel file into a SQL Table.

I am trying to select the date column but I get 
"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while inserting datetime"

My Query is

```
Select 
CONVERT(datetime2, SS.OrderDate) Date_Created
--CAST(SS.OrderDate as datetime2) Date_Created
FROM Table SS (nolock)
```

Both of these lines fail.

My date column look like this:

```
43613
43612
43611
```

Which excel can format back into (does anyone know how? what format is this?)

```
5/28/2019
5/27/2019
5/26/2019
```

How can I get the same to be done in SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that this works for most dates.

```
select dateadd(day, 43613, '1899-12-30')
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `1899-12-31` if you're not subtracting the `1`?

Comment: @Dai The 12/30 is correct provided the date is after 1900-02-28.  1900 was not a leap year, but excel thinks is was.

Answer (score 0):

Excel "serial" dates are the number of days since `1900-01-01` (where `1` is `1900-01-01`, so subtract 1 first)

You can convert it like so:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT( date, DATEADD( day, SS.OrderDate - 1, '1900-01-01' ) ) AS OrderDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option is to use the implicit conversion of a **float** to **datetime**.  Notice the minus 2.0

**Example**

```
Select AsInt       = convert(datetime,43613-2.0)
      ,WithDecimal = convert(datetime,43613.5-2.0)
```

**Returns**

```
AsInt                    WithDecimal
2019-05-28 00:00:00.000  2019-05-28 12:00:00.000
```

Now, IF your column is a varchar, perhaps something like this

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([OrderDate] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
('43613'),
('43612'),
('43611')

select AsDateTime = convert(datetime,0+[OrderDate]-2.0)
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
AsDateTime
2019-05-28 00:00:00.000
2019-05-27 00:00:00.000
2019-05-26 00:00:00.000
```